# List/GridView scrolling manually forever after last row

Tags: android, listview, gridview, scroll

I have lists/gridviews in android applications.
When I "slide" my finger (botton to top), the scrolls works perfectly, but in the last row the scroll continues scrolling if I continues sliding.

So, the rows ascend with the scroll until disappear.

When I take my finger from the screen, the rows appears "falling down" like a scrolling down.

How can I "limit" the scroll to stop scrolling in the last row? (like scroll of the LinearLayout)

My listView code:

```
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/skills_listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:listSelector="#00000000"
        android:scrollingCache="false"
        android:smoothScrollbar="true" >
    </ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`